# What token does a "peek" operation refer to in Lexical analysis?

Tags: compilers, lexical-analysis

Given a grammar for a space delimited list of words:

```
S     -> word { space word }
word  -> [a-zA-Z]+
space -> [ \t]+
```

And given the input "Hello World", what token would a `peek()` operation return?

Comment: Where did you come across this operation?  Can you cite the source and the context in which it was used?  Did the source define it?  I'm not sure there is a standard, accepted meaning for it -- I suspect it might be up to the document where you saw that to define what they meant by that.

Comment: I have seen two answers: 1. Return the current token ("Hello") without advancing the input stream and 2. return the next token ("World") without advancing the input stream.  I want to know which definition is most common in compilers.